# Asymptote: set camera inside the box defined by the axis

Tags: 3d, asymptote

The first figure is the (almost) the example `elevation.asy` from the [demo gallery](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/3D%20graphs/index.html).

I'd like to do an animation of a moving camera navigating in-between the peaks (a bit like a *walkthrough* in architecture software, or if the animation was a video captured from a plane in a hilly landscape).

I fail because I when I choose a camera position in the box defined by the axis (e.g. `currentprojection=perspective(camera=(0.1,.3,.5),autoadjust=true);`), the camera is automatically adjusted to the nearest position *outside* the box (see second figure). If I specify `autoadjust=false` I get an error (`Error: /configurationerror in --setpagedevice--`). I am really not sure that it is possible to do what I want because in the interactive mode (when compiled with option `-V`), I cannot set such a POV.

**Question:** Would it be possible to choose a POV *inside* the box defined by the axis?

With `currentprojection=perspective(0.8,1,1);`:
[image]

With `currentprojection=perspective(camera=(0.1,.3,.5),autoadjust=true);`:
[image]

Code for first picture:

```
import graph3;
import grid3;
import palette;

currentprojection=perspective(0.8,1,1);

size(400,300,IgnoreAspect);

defaultrender.merge=true;

real f(pair z) {return cos(2*pi*z.x)*sin(2*pi*z.y);}

surface s=surface(f,(-1/2,-1/2),(1/2,1/2),50,Spline);

draw(s,mean(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow())),black);

grid3(XYZgrid);
```

Comment: Wild guess: Use negative values for the `camera` position.

Comment: @Werner I tried but the same behaviour occurs (except the adjusted camera position is on the other side, still targeting (0,0,0)).

Comment: Not sure that it is possible. Possible workaround is `zoom` (but the perspective does not change). Another way is to eliminate some Bézier patches of the surface (no XYZaxis) with respect to the camera (see the `partialsurface.asy` example) to avoid `camera too closed`.

Comment: Have you tried interactive zooming with `asy -V`? 
It looks that you need to adjust the `angle`.
I've got a close view with
`currentprojection=perspective(camera=(1,-0.3,2.6),angle=4,autoadjust=false);`.

Comment: @g.kov I did try interactive zooming, but does not make me travel "on" the object, it just gives a closer view (just as zooming when you take a picture in the mountains is not the same as taking a picture while flying towards the mountains, if you see what I mean).

Comment: @O.G. With `zoom`: see comment above. I will try your second suggestion and give an update when I have something new.

Comment: possibly hard coded... because in Asymptote you can specify "ppi" and it will calculate the size of the output. Putting camera inside leads to infinitely large output.